# Passing input id as jquery function paramenter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery.

I am trying to create a reusable function that will replace the text of a input field.

I pass in the field I want to change as one parameter and the new text as another parameter.

I figured I would try it out with some radio buttons.

**HTML**

```
<label>
<input type="radio" name="optradio" onClick="replaceText(txt_recipient, 'All')" value="0" checked>All</label>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="optradio" onClick="replaceText(txt_recipient, 'Geo')" value="1">Geographical Area</label>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="optradio" onClick="replaceText(txt_recipient, '')" value="2">Specific User</label> 
<input type="text"id="txt_recipient" name="txt_recipient" value="All" />
```

**JS**

```
function replaceText(field, newtext) {
    document.getElementById(field).text(newtext);
};
```

I originally toyed with the idea of

```
 function replaceText(field, newtext) {
          $(field).text(newtext);  
      };
```

but that didn't seem to work either. Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`field` is the actual element so just set the input `value` property.

```
function replaceText(field, newtext) {
    field.value = newtext;
}
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/039v0wst/1/**

with jQuery

```
function replaceText(field, newtext) {
    $(field).val(newtext);
}
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/rgen7vLv/1/**

Answer (score 0):

It is no longer recommended to declare event handlers inline in the HTML attributes.

Using a more modern syntax, I'd include a data attribute that specifies the text in the destination, the update your target using the string from the data attribute.

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
  $("#txt_recipient").val($(this).data("text"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="optradio" data-text="All" value="0" checked>All</label>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="optradio" data-text="Geo" value="1">Geographical Area</label>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="optradio" data-text="" value="2">Specific User</label> 
<input type="text"id="txt_recipient" name="txt_recipient" value="All" />
```

Comment: Hmm this is close. However, I wanted to pass the value of text field and the new text. This just takes the hardcoded text field inserts the parent text.

Answer (score 0):

First of all give unique names:

```
<input type="radio" name="optradio1" onClick="replaceText(txt_recipient, 'All')" value="0" checked>All</label>
```

Geographical Area

then js

```
$('input[name$="optradio1"]').val("newtext")
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you pass the field id with ' '

E.g;

'txt_recipient' instead of 'txt_recipient